# Run a Windows Service on IIS

Tags: c#, windows, service

I want to run a service, like Windows Service that will run every hour on IIS. I do not want to use the service locally on my machine as it would dependent on the machine being keep on for the service to work. 
Is there a way to achieve this? I have tried to find a solution but could not find a clear answer.

Comment: IIS also is dependent on the machine being kept on. What do you want exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A windows service and an IIS application are different. It sounds like you want to run a recurring task for your website, for that I would recommend something like [hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) or [quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/). Both offer persistence options so that they can run even if the application is restarted or recycled.